Goroutine not starting in shared library
I'm trying to create a pam module to be used for authorization with SSH.
Unfortunately every goroutine does not start within the PAM module, if it was used within SSH flow. It does indeed work with pamtester without any issues.
Here is the code:
package main

/*
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
typedef const char cchar_t;
*/
import "C"
import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {}

//export pam_sm_authenticate
func pam_sm_authenticate(pamh *C.pam_handle_t, flags C.int, argc C.int, argv **C.cchar_t) C.int {
    log.Printf("golib.so: before start goroutine")
    go func() {
        // This will not happen and the whole program will hang from
        // here on...
        log.Printf("golib.so: something out of the goroutine")
    }()
    log.Printf("golib.so: after start goroutine")

    return C.PAM_SUCCESS
}

//export pam_sm_setcred
func pam_sm_setcred(pamh *C.pam_handle_t, flags C.int, argc C.int, argv **C.cchar_t) C.int {
    return C.PAM_IGNORE
}

Environment

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
SSH: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Go: go version go1.22.5 linux/amd64
pemtester: 0.1.2

Similar issues

golang/go#57394
golang/go#15538
golang/go#15556

So far non of those tickets helped me to solve the issue.
My main problem is not that I even intent to use goroutines but if I'm using http.Client goroutines are everywhere.
So: I'm happy for proposals to make the goroutines in the context of a PAM modules within SSH work or to do HTTP requests without goroutines. 
Thanks for your support!

Start by adding proper synchronization to ensure that the goroutine is actually going get scheduled before the calling function returns

This is a simple example that should demonstrate where the problem starts. Even http.Get(..) does not work and there I have no regular way to change the synchronization there. But not even the first log entry appears. Where nothing happens than just logging something.

Yes, but starting with a correct minimal example will rule out possible issues. Make a goroutine that must be scheduled and return during the call to make sure that even works.
